# How to enable btrfs zstd compression

Tags: btrfs, compression, lubuntu

I saw mention of zstd [in the documentation](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Compression) (4.14 and later), so I figured to give it a try.

Starting from lubuntu 17.10, I upgraded my kernel to 4.15:

```
# uname -sr
Linux 4.15.0-041500-generic
```

However, neither man, nor btrfs commands acnowledge the fact that I'm now running a kernel supposedly capable of using this comression algorithm:

```
# btrfs filesystem defrag -czstd -rv .*
ERROR: unknown compression type zstd
```

What did I "forget" to upgrade?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need to update `btrfs-progs` to a version that supports zstd. Zstd support was initially added in version 4.13.

Answer (score 0):

The follow algos are supported today by actual kernel:

- zlib
- lzo
- zstd

zstd are the newest one. If yu use older Kernel, try the older algos.

To compress previously uncompressed data, you can do this via console, for example, as follows:

Also with newer kernels:

```
sudo btrfs filesystem defragment -r -v -czstd /
```

With older and newer kernels:

```
sudo btrfs filesystem defragment -r -v -czlib /
sudo btrfs filesystem defragment -r -v -clzo /
```

The compression for new files can be configured p.e. on fstab:

```
UUID=yourxxxUUIDxxx /   btrfs   defaults, compress, subvol=@    0   0

UUID=yourxxxUUIDxxx     /home   btrfs   defaults, compress, subvol=@home,   0
```

You can replace the "compress" above by p.e. one of the follow:

```
compress=zlib
compress=lzo
compress=zstd

compress-force=zlib
compress-force=lzo
compress-force=zstd
```

You can replace the "1" by numbers "1" to "15":
compress=zstd:1
compress-force=zstd:1

Comment: `You can replace the "compress" above by p.e. one of the follow:`

What does "p.e." mean?